# Django MySQL - correct way to connect

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I have been using Django to connect to MySQL on my local computer and I have been using the following method to connect:

1. run pip install mysqlclient and update the requirements.txt file appropriately.
2. update the database connection in settings.py to something like this:

   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
   'NAME': ......,
   'USER': ......,

A bit of a problem arose when I started to use a Dockerfile to try to run the Django app.   When I build the Dockerfile and then run the django project, I start to get errors:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

It seems to me that there are 2 potential solutions to this:

1 ) Adjust the Dockerfile so that it installs the software necessary for mysqlclient.   This is actually a bit trickier than expected.   Could you please make some recommendations for python:3.10.0a5-alpine3.12.

2 ) I was reading about mysql-connector-python.   At present I have not got this to work.    I installed it using pip, updated the requirements file and then changed the settings.py file to something like this:

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
'NAME': ....,
'USER': ....,
```

I have two area's of concern and I would really appreciate some help:

1 ) Which of these methods is the most appropriate way to connect to MySQL using Django (or is there an even more appropriate method) ?   Could you please let me know the exact procedure for updating my project.

2 ) I am concerned about matching the appropriate version of the library to connect to my version of MySQL.   For example, I have MySQL 5.7.29 on my Mac.   There are lots of different versions of mysql-connector-python (the current version is 8.0.23).   How do I make sure that the version of mysql-connector-python is appropriate for my version of MySQL ?   Similarly how do I make sure that the install commands for the Dockerfile are appropriate for my version of MySQL ?

Thanks

Mark

The Dockerfile has changed a bit, as I have tried different techniques, but this is an example:

```
FROM python:3.10.0a5-alpine3.12

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1


# Echo the Environment variables to help with debugging
RUN echo $DJANGO_DEBUG
RUN echo $API_ENVIRONMENT

EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /code/

RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput

RUN python3 manage.py makemigrations

RUN python3 manage.py migrate

ENTRYPOINT gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --workers 3 brokerdata.wsgi
```

Comment: Can you share the dockerfile? Have you installed the mysql client in your dockerfile?

Comment: Hi Iain, I have added an example dockerfile.   Thanks, Mark

Comment: You have to install mysqlclient, I think `mysql-client` or `py3-mysqlclient` should be what you need: `RUN apk update && apk add py3-mysqlclient`